# Why did Dr. Chiren ask Dr. Ido that question?

Tags: alita-battle-angel

In [*Alita: Battle Angel* (2019)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alita:_Battle_Angel), while Dr. Ido is carrying the fragile Alita, Dr. Chiren asks:

> **Dr. Chiren**: *You think you can replace us that easily?* Bring her back as many times as you like.

Dr. Ido is trying to fix Alita. He never tried to replace anything. What was she referring to in her question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As shown in a flashback, Chiren and Ido had a daughter together. Chiren is accusing Ido of replacing "us" (herself and their dead daughter) with Alita.

This is especially understandable because the robotic body Chiren gives to Alita after finding her was originally meant to be used by their daughter, who was wheelchair bound. Giving this object of great sentimental value to Alita is a pretty big deal.